# How to find mongo document by parrameter in internal map (better with Spring MongoTemplate)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have collection with docs:

```
{
    a:"a1",
    b:{
       "bla1-1":{c:1,d:2},
       "bla1-2":{c:3,d:4}
      }
},
{
    a:"a2",
    b:{
       "bla2-1":{c:1,d:2},
       "bla2-2":{c:5,d:6}
      }
}
```

How i can find document, which contains c == 5? In my case:

```
{
    a:"a2",
    b:{
       "bla2-1":{c:1,d:2},
       "bla2-2":{c:5,d:6}
    }
}
```

P.S. I use Spring **MongoTemplate** in my app. And it will be better to see MongoTemplate usage in answer.

Comment: For your current structure you could use following query in Mongo console:
`db.collection.find({$or: [{"b.bla1-1.c": 5}, {"b.bla1-2.c": 5}, {"b.bla2-1.c": 5}, {"b.bla2-2.c": 5}]})`
But is structure of your documents different for objects in collection?
If so this query is not supporting this issue. And I'm affraid that it could be problematic to write one.

Comment: @MarcinArmatys Unfortunately I dont know keys of map

Comment: @MarcinArmatys Actualy i need request like {"b.*.c": 5}

Comment: Please see @Tom answer - I think it can be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done using pure mongo, I suggest to change the schema.
But this can be done using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```
db.test.find({
    $where: function () {
        for (var prop in this.b) {
            if (this.b[prop].c == 5) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```